# Add ".active" class to the current page's link in a menu using jQuery or PHP

Tags: php, jquery, css

I need to add `.active` class on active task's menu link on the page. I am working on localhost, here are few example URLs:

```
http://localhost/webapp/index.php?task=validate
http://localhost/webapp/index.php?task=register
```

and the structure of the menu:

```
    <div class="menu">
       <ul class="sf-menu">
          <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
          <li><a href="?task=validator">Validar</a></li>
          <li><a href="?task=register">Registro</a></li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is missing the concrete code you have that question with - written by yourself so that you can make clear where you run into a programming problem, then formulating a programming question.

Comment: Do you want to do this on the client side (jQuery/JavaScript) or server side (using PHP)?

Comment: Hi, i would like to do this on client/side using jQuery/Javascript i was using superfish plugin but it didn't work

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use jQuery to loop through all links and compare their URLs with `location`. Here is an example:

```
$(".sf-menu a").filter(function(){
    return this.href == location.href.replace(/#.*/, "");
}).addClass("active");
```

Comment: Note: This works only if you are matching parameters in the url. 

For example, it will not add the active class if the url is /hello/world?param=1 and your a link is 

`<a href="/hello/world"></a>`

Comment: I am facing same problem here my URL is /hello/world?param=1 how can I add active class in here.This code is working until page load,after finished load active is not working