# jQuery navbar: Hover changing colors

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to get some help with a jQuery issue.  I have my site with a navbar and currently when you hover over one of the navbar links, it changes color.  What I want it to do is when you click on a link and go to a different page, I want the current pages link to stay the hovered color even if I hover over it again.  All other links should be the default color unless they are hovered over (they should then change color).

Here is the link to the page as an example:
http://chrisliaw.net63.net/portfolio/

The home link should already be the highlighted color, but when I hover over it and then move the mouse away it changes to the default grey color.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ".active" class to the current page's link in a menu using jQuery or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349046/add-active-class-to-the-current-pages-link-in-a-menu-using-jquery-or-php)

Comment: Sorry, new to the site.  I will provide a better post next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OO... This i done with some IF statements.. You can do this in 2 ways:
1. Use Js to  see on wich page you currently are .. and give some class to that link 
2. User PHP to do this validation

Here are some examples:

With JS:

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="#" id='home-page'>Home</a>
 <a href="#" id='about-page'>About</a>
 <a href="#" id='some-page'>some page</a>
</div>

var sPath=window.location.pathname;
 var sPage = sPath.substring(sPath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  if(sPage == "home.html")
   {
     $("#menu a").removeClass("Active-Link"); // reset all links
     $("#home").addClass("Active-Link"); // get current page link the class
   }
```

With PHP

```
  <div id="menu">
    <a href="#" id='home-page' <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "home.html"){ echo " class='current-page' ";}?> >Home</a>
     <a href="#" id='about-page' <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "home.html"){ echo " class='current-page' ";}?>>About</a>
     <a href="#" id='some-page' <?php if(basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) == "home.html"){ echo " class='current-page' ";}?>>some page</a>
    </div>
```

Hope, this is the code that you want .. :) Try it :)