# Highlight current page on the navbar

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, highlight, navbar

I know this question have been asked several times but I've tried their versions and I can't get it to work.

I have a Navbar made out of HTML and CSS code.

```
<ul>
<li><a href="index.php">Start</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Uppgifter</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="">Webbens Historia</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="../../sidor/historia/css/index.html">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a href="../../sidor/historia/html/index.html">HTML</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="../../sidor/table/index.html">Tabell</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Placeholder</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact.php">Kontakta</a></li>
```

This code is insterted to every page I have with 3 simple lines.

```
<nav>
<?php include("includes/menu.html");?>
</nav>
```

I do of course have a whole separate file with the CSS for this but I don't think I need to show that.

I've looked around on Google ALOT for solutions and I've realised that the BEST solution is JavaScript / jQuery. The problem is that I don't know anything at all about that.

Could someone please show me a good solution for this?

Thanks!
/Casper

Comment: You will probably want to do something like add a page parameter to your links specifying which page was clicked.  Then in your javascript file pull the get parameter to find out what page is active and then apply the highlight css to that link. `href="/sidor/historia/css/index.html?page=css` and `href="/sidor/historia/html/index.html?page=html`

Comment: It would probably be a good idea to work on some javascript jquery tutorials.. Here is one site that is helpful http://codecademy.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349046/add-active-class-to-the-current-pages-link-in-a-menu-using-jquery-or-php