# Adding class to to specific href element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor, href

I'm trying to add a class to the anchor of the current URL in the menu navigation in order to differentiate it. I've done research and using this snippet

```
'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname
```

I'm able to target the URL I'm trying to select. However, I can't find to figure out the exact syntax to add the class to the anchor element. I've tried many variations of this snippet

```
$('[href="http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname 
+ '"]').addClass("current-menu-item");
```

and nothing has worked. I'm wondering if I'm missing something obvious or if there is a more elegant way to approach this problem. Any advice is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @Popnoodles correct me if I'm wrong but isn't the :active property simply while a link is being clicked? I'm talking about targeting the navigation item for the user's current page.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add ".active" class to the current page's link in a menu using jQuery or PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13349046/add-active-class-to-the-current-pages-link-in-a-menu-using-jquery-or-php)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('nav a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]').addClass('current-menu-item');
});
```

Your current selector is too generic, it would target any links in your page. Just change the `nav a` selector in the above example to match your specific HTML.

From [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/add-active-navigation-class-based-on-url/)

Comment: Currently `'http://' + window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname` produces the exact URL of the anchor I'm trying to target. The issue is adding a class to the href with a specific URL.

Answer (score 0):

```
var href = window.location.href.match(/[A-Za-z\_]+$/);
if(!href || !href[0] )
    return false;
$("[active='"+href+"']").addClass("active");
```

Comment: Even though your code may be correct, you should also include a comment or explanation to not look suspicious.